# Is it possible to add a FROM to SMS with new clickatell API?

Tags: json, api, sms, sms-gateway, clickatell

The new platform API at [Clickatell](https://www.clickatell.com/) seems to not allow you to add "from" to the JSON payload, complaining that it not a 2 way integration, but the is no possibility to add a text moniker to the short codes so that instead of the number "COMPANY" would appear

This is possible with the older api. Clickatell endpoints, and wondering if anyone can confirm that this functionality is actually removed, but better still suggest  a workaround if it is

Answer (score 1):

They used to allow this a long time ago (TPOA - transmission path originating address)... looks like the API's haven't been updated to reflect that now it's not a free-for-all, but restricted to short or long codes you have purchased via them.

Answer (score 0):

The Platform account doesn't have the sender ID feature - however, the FROM parameter is still available for any two-way integration with an active two-way subscription. The subscription can either be for a short code or a long number, if specified in the message submission. If the feature is supported by suppliers and network operators, these messages will deliver with the short code or long number specified.